# Using Power Automate to make SharePoint document libraries from a CSV

Tags: csv, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have an upcoming task of making over 100 document libraries for the team here. I have all this data in a spreadsheet, Library name and (ideally) the list of choices for a column.

I've read that Power Automate can help here, since the organisation has blocked the use of PowerShell, much to my chagrin.

Is is possible to push a CSV through Power Automate and it somehow create all the libraries I need? The internet seems to tell me this is indeed possible, but I can't find out exactly how. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but PowerShell would be much quicker.. In this instance, I think the correct thing is challenging the organisation's decision. I work in Financial Services, and everything is locked down as we're a regulated industry, but I still have PowerShell access because it's required to do the job effectively.

In the event your organization still decide not to provide PowerShell access, the process to do this is largely the same as PowerShell:

1. Store the file in OneDrive/SharePoint
2. PA reads the file from OneDrive/SharePoint
3. Iterate over the data in the spreadsheet, for each row
4. Create new library using the spreadsheet data
5. You would use the REST endpoints for creating document libraries which are explained in the below links:
   https://www.alanps1.io/power-platform/flow/flow-create-sharepoint-library-rest-api-with-power-automate/